# Stock options: what happens if I leave a company and then an acquisition is finalized?

Tags: employee-stock-options, option-exercise

If this situation occurs and I have 75% of my shares vested and I have a 60 day window to exercise the vested options upon termination (my choice not company's choice) can I reap the financial benefits of the sale and much higher strike price even though it is finalized after I leave but within my window of 60 days?

Second part of question, is the sale of a company and the exercise of the options based on the day public knowledge the sale has occurred or is it after the financials settle as my 60 day window may be in jeopardy here?

Answer (score 2):

When you exercise your options, you come up with cash to buy the shares. This makes you an owner of the company for shares at the share price your options let you have. Ideally, your share price is at a significant discount to what the company is worth.

Being a shareholder, you gain from any share price appreciation in a sale. The only thing the "60-day window" applies to is whether you come up with the cash to buy fast enough, or your shares get permanently deleted from the company finances, where everyone else potentially makes more, you make nothing.

The sale of the company is based on whenever the sell finalizes, which is between your company and the acquiring company.

Answer (score -1):

Having stock options means that you have worked for and rightfully earned a part of the company's capital appreciation. Takeover of the company would indicate someone is interested in the company (something should be valuable). It would be unwise to not strike before the period lapses since the strike price is always lower than market price and takeovers generally increases stock values ... it is capital gains all the way my friend. Good luck.

*observations not in professional capacity. pls consult a professional for investment related advice.